# How do I maintain all files in a single shared location despite having two WIX installers?

Tags: wix

I've set the Product Id to "*" and AllowSameVersionUpgrades="yes" so I can have 2 installers with some common features, but each of them has 1 unique feature: a merge module that installs a file (file-A and file-B, respectively) in a shared location.

The problem is that, if I install Installer-B after Installer-A, the file-A from the shared location gets deleted and only file-B is copied. I also get two identical entries in the "Programs and Features" list.

Is there a way to maintain all the files in the shared location when installing Installer-B?

Answer (score 0):

You may need to clarify somewhat. It's not clear why you are mentioning AllowSameVersionUpgrades because you seem to be installing two products side by side, which makes it irrelevant.  You also mention that you have a merge module that installs a file in a shared location, but then you mention only the file from B is installed if you install A and then B. But that's normal. There's one file, as you mention, and that file goes into the same location, so there cannot be a duplicate file in the same location. It's shared, as you say, which means that both A and B will use it, and if you uninstall A or B then it will stay behind because that's the way reference counting works (internally using the component id for the shared file). So this seems to be all working normally and shouldn't be a problem. If you want A and B to use their own private copies of the file then don't install to the same shared location.

In the list of installed programs, again, that is normal. You're not doing an upgrade - you are installing two separate products so you get two entries in the list. Just change the name to fix that, and again, you're not doing an upgrade - you are installing two products side by side. If you want to do an upgrade, look at the MajorUpgrade element, UIpgradeCode and related.

Comment: Yeah I think I should have add that I also have a Custom Action running when REMOVE="ALL" that removes some files that are created by the app itself and not the installer. So this CA gets triggered even when a second installer runs on a previous installed version. So there I have a problem because it shouldn't do any uninstallation at all.